# Apache Tika parser char limit exception

Tags: java, apache-tika

I am using Apache Tike parser v1.24. We have large size PDF files. When parsing these we get the following error:

```
Exception: Your document contained more than 100000 characters, and so your requested limit has been reached. To receive the full text of the document, increase your limit. (Text up to the limit is however available).]
```

I tried to setting the parameter of `bodyContentHandler` to `-1`. But it didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079433/how-to-read-large-files-using-tika

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? With no code it is hard to tell what you did wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Please use the pdfbox to split pdf file per page - look at class Splitter